# AWS CLI command to copy files from s3 to local machine fails with InvalidAccessKeyId

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, aws-cli

Hi folks I am following a tutorial on the AWS platform and I am stuck at a point where I have to copy some files from an s3 to local machine. I used the following command to do that:

```
aws s3 cp s3://wildrydes-us-east-1/WebApplication/1_StaticWebHosting/website ./ --recursive
```

However what I get is an error:

> fatal error: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

Comment: You need to configure your AWS CLI with your IAM users access key and secret key id.

Comment: Yes I have configured by generating a new HTTPS Git credentials for AWS CodeCommit and setting them in the command line but still the error seems to appear @hephalump

Comment: Those aren’t the credentials you’re looking for. In AWS IAM your user has access keys, you need to configure them in the AWS CLI.

Comment: Thanks alot @hephalump yes now it works after creating a access key and setting it in cli.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments above, you must create and use an Access Key and a Secret Access Key as described in the tutorial. That will get rid of the current error. However, you will also need to grant the IAM user that is doing the copy the "AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess" policy and wait 5 minutes. This gives the IAM user permission to read from S3.